# nancyfx - serving static files from a parent folder

Tags: c#, nancy

I want to serve my static files from a parent directory so I can modify them for easy development while the application is still running. I have tried to add a static content convention in my Bootstrapper like so:

```
this.Conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
  StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("content", @"../../content")
);
base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
```

But it is still not able to find those static files. Is it not possible to serve from a parent folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with the StaticContentConventionBuilder; we explicitly don't allow this for security reasons. We make sure whatever file that's requested by the user always falls within the scope of the web root, otherwise people could potentially use some path manipulation to retrieve files you didn't want them to.

If you really have to do this (although your reasoning makes little sense when you can edit the files in the web root just as easily as anywhere else), then you will have to write the convention from scratch yourself - it's a Func.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still loving Nancy!

Comment: i feel like the best response to to this would be 'its dangerous but here is how you do it', rather than 'figure it out for yourself its not hard'

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `IRootPathProvider` in debug builds and return whatever path you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you add these 2 files to your project:
https://gist.github.com/elliotwoods/4822f9c512b4f464534d9e01eb6d21b1

Then you can use a custom static folder like so:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);

        nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
#if (DEBUG)
            UnsafeStaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/StaticContent", "../../StaticContent")
#else
            StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/StaticContent", "StaticContent")
#endif
            );
    }

}
```

There are very good reasons for why you wouldn't want to do this in anything which goes public. In my sitation:

1. The TargetDir is not tracked by git
2. During Debug mode I want to edit the content and see the result whilst the app is running
3. My app will only ever be run on a private network

Then I think this routine is safe